Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'SafeERC20: low-level call failed'
// hardhat.config.js
require("hardhat-deploy")
require("dotenv").config()
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers");
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan");

const SEPOLIA_RPC_URL = process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
const ALCHEMY_MAINNET_URL = process.env.ALCHEMY_MAINNET_URL

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  // solidity: "0.8.24",
    solidity: {
        compilers: [
            { version: "0.8.7" },
            { version: "0.6.6" },
            { version: "0.6.12" },
            { version: "0.4.19" },],
    },

    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",

    networks: {
        localhost: {
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545/",
            chainId: 31337,
            blockConfirmations: 6,
            gas: "auto",
        },
        sepolia:{
            url:SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
            accounts:[PRIVATE_KEY],
            chainId:11155111,
            blockConfirmations: 1,
            gas:"auto",
          },
        hardhat: {
            forking: {
                url:ALCHEMY_MAINNET_URL,
            },
            chainId:31337,
            gas: "auto",
        },
    },
    sourcify: {
        enabled: true,
    },
    etherscan: {
        apiKey: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
    },
    namedAccounts: {
        deployer: {
            default: 0,
        },
        user: {
            default: 2,
        },
    },
}

// aaveBorrow.js

const { getNamedAccounts, ethers } = require("hardhat");
const { getWeth } = require("./getWeth");

async function main() {

    // the protocol treats everthing as an ERC20 token
    await getWeth();
    const AMOUNT = ethers.parseEther("1.5")
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
    const signer = await ethers.getSigner(deployer);
    console.log("Signer and deployer :",signer,deployer);
    // Lending Pool Address Provider : 0xB53C1a33016B2DC2fF3653530bfF1848a515c8c5
    const lendingPool = await getLendingPool(signer);
    const lendingPoolAddress = lendingPool.runner.address

    console.log(`Lending Pool Address ${lendingPoolAddress}`);

    // before depositing we need to approve aave contract
    const iWethAdd = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2";
    // approve

    await approveErc20(iWethAdd, lendingPool.runner.address, AMOUNT, signer);
    console.log("Depositing...");
    try {
        await lendingPool.deposit(iWethAdd, AMOUNT, deployer, 0);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    console.log("Deposited...");

}

async function getLendingPool(signer) {
    

    const lendingPoolAddressesProvider = await ethers.getContractAt(
        "ILendingPoolAddressesProvider",
        "0xB53C1a33016B2DC2fF3653530bfF1848a515c8c5",
        signer);

    const lendingPoolAddress = await lendingPoolAddressesProvider.getLendingPool();
    const lendingPool = await ethers.getContractAt(
        "ILendingPool",
        lendingPoolAddress,
        signer
    );

    return lendingPool

}

async function approveErc20(erc20Address, spenderAddress, amountToSpend, signer) {

    const erc20 = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", erc20Address, signer);

    const tx = await erc20.approve(spenderAddress, amountToSpend)
    await tx.wait(1);
    console.log("Token of approved tx: ",tx);
    console.log(`Token Apporved`);

}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))



I faced this issue bcz of the incorrect approval amount.
Try giving a big amount of approval to the WETH contract for LendingPool contract to spend.
wethContract.approve(lendingPoolAddress,ethers.parseEther("100")) //some big values


may be passing incorrect values of amount to either approve method or deposit method also causes this issue.
And having less balance in the wallet also causes the issue.
As you are using hardhat node low balance is not the cause.
